# How to update global variable when window closes?

Tags: javascript, popup, global-variables

First time here. I'm trying to code something with these features with Javascript.

First, if a link is clicked, and **there is no existing popup window**, a popup window will be created, navigating to that link.

However, if second link is clicked, and **there is an existing popup window**, it'll run some AJAX function. We will not navigate to that link.

However, if another link is clicked, and **the popup window has been closed**, it'll open the window again (and navigate to that link).

The only way I can think of that allows me to solve this is using a global variable, however it's not working out. Can someone help please? Thanks!

Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kding/j9LYL/16/)

The HTML

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:displayWindow=openwindowPreview(1, displayWindow); return false">1</a>
<br/>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:displayWindow=openwindowPreview(4, displayWindow); return false">4</a>
```

The Javascript

```
var displayWindow = null;
var test = 'test';

function openwindowPreview(id, winObject) {
    // check if the window already exists
    if (winObject != null) {
        // the window has already been created, but did the user close it?
        // if so, then reopen it. Otherwise make it the active window.
        if (!winObject.closed) {
            winObject.focus();
            return winObject;
        }
    }

    if (test != 'test') {
        if (winObject.closed) {
            test = 'test';
        } else {
            alert('ajax');
        }
    }

    // if we get here, then the window hasn't been created yet, or it
    // was closed by the user.
    if (test == 'test') {
        var urlDisplayID= "file.php?ID=" + id;
        window.open(urlDisplayID, 'width=' + screen.width, 'height=' + screen.height);
        test = 'tested';
    }
}
```

Basically, only allow one instance of the window at once, and only display the first instance, while other instances (different URLs — because of the parameter) are sent to the server via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

in your case I think this maybe as your need.

```
var openWindows = {};

function openwindowPreview(id) {

// if we get here, then the window hasn't been created yet, or it
// was closed by the user.
var urlDisplayID= "file.php?ID=" + id;
//set id as the window name, so if the window already opened,
//the open method will find the opened window with the window name
var opened =  window.open(urlDisplayID, id,'width=' + screen.width, 'height=' + screen.height);
if(opened === openWindows[id]){
    alert("ajax");
}else{
    openWindows[id] = opened();
}
```

}